# How to Create a Responsive Hero Ad

Tags: html, css, e-commerce, ads

I am trying to create a responsive Hero and banner ad for a friends site. I want to mimic the layout of "Childrens Place" as far as the ad up top and the hero image in the middle.

I have a Shopify store and can input a hero image easily, I am new to coding and want to include a split on the image itself meaning that half of the image is "men" the other is "women" and when a user hovers over men it will take them to the mens selection (if clicked) and vice versa. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction on learning this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for the split I would basically make two ankers a tag. In the css make the width 50%; margin: 0. Float one right and one left. If you want the a tag's to be on top off the image position it absolute.

Try it out and have fun! 
If there are any further questions or you need help on your way ask it.
Greetz Jens